# Edit hash values as per the array values and conditions

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a hash as follows:

```
random_data = {
0=>{"ABC"=>"201604", "CDE"=>"0002874", "TPP"=>"000004971821467", "APD"=>"00182", "PRODUCTID"=>"ACH", "OPP"=>"00000000000176564", "CTC"=>"00000000000286920"}, 
1=>{"ABC"=>"301604", "CDE"=>"0001074", "TPP"=>"000004971821467", "APD"=>"00182", "PRODUCTID"=>"ACH", "OPP"=>"00000000000119964", "CTC"=>"00000000000211920"}
}
```

and the 2 arrays as follows:

```
arr1 = [CHAR,NUMBER,NUMBER,NUMBER,CHAR,NUMBER,CHAR]
arr2 = [6,(7,0),(15,0),(5,0),3,(15,2),17]
```

The elements of arr1 and arr2 are mapped with the hash values, the conditions are as follows:

1. if array `arr1` 's element is char, do nothing with the hash's value.
2. if array `arr1` 's element is NUMBER, the corresponding element in hash `random_data` should get converted to integer, i.e the leading zeros should be removed.

For example, arr1[1] is 'Number', hence for every second element of hash, leading zeros should get removed.

ie. "CDE"=>"0002874" should become "CDE"=>"2874"

3. If `arr1` is NUMBER and `arr2` element's second digit is not 0 then decimal should be added in the hash.
   For exemple:
   arr1[5] = Number
   arr2[5] = (15,2)

then 5th element in hash `OPP` should become like this "OPP"=>"1199.64" i.e for decimal is added for 2 places (15,2)

The outputs is expected as follows:

```
random_data = {
0=>{"ABC"=>"201604", "CDE"=>"2874", "TPP"=>"4971821467", "APD"=>"182", "PRODUCTID"=>"ACH", "OPP"=>"1765.64", "CTC"=>"00000000000286920"}, 
1=>{"ABC"=>"301604", "CDE"=>"1074", "TPP"=>"4971821467", "APD"=>"182", "PRODUCTID"=>"ACH", "OPP"=>"1199.64", "CTC"=>"00000000000211920"}
}
```

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: Unless you have shown what you had already tried, we are not going to do your homework for you. Also, `arr1` and `arr2` are **not valid** ruby objects.

Comment: In `(15,0)` and `(15,2)` what is the significance of `15`? What is the significance of `6`, `3` and `17`?

Comment: Why do you need to run this, what do you try to achieve? I am pretty sure when you explain what you try to achieve, then there is a better and easier to understand way to generate the same result.

Comment: @mudasobwa

I was trying to add logic like as below

random_source_data_hash.each do |test| 
  test[1].each do |k,v|
    <loop for arr1 > 

  end
end

I am not sure how do i start a loop for the arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr1 = %w| CHAR NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER CHAR NUMBER CHAR |
  #=> ["CHAR", "NUMBER", "NUMBER", "NUMBER", "CHAR", "NUMBER", "CHAR"]
arr2 = [6, [7,0], [15,0], [5,0], 3, [15,2], 17]
```

```
enum = arr1.zip(arr2).map { |type, obj| type=="CHAR" ? type : obj.last }.to_enum
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["CHAR", 0, 0, 0, "CHAR", 2, "CHAR"]:each> 

random_data.each do |k,h|
  h.update(h) do |*,v|
    obj = enum.next 
    case obj 
    when "CHAR"
      v
    else
      x = v.to_i
      x = x.to_f/10**obj if obj > 0
      x.to_s
    end  
  end
  enum.rewind
end
  #=> {0=>{"ABC"=>"201604", "CDE"=>"2874", "TPP"=>"4971821467", "APD"=>"182",
  #        "PRODUCTID"=>"ACH", "OPP"=>"0.17", "CTC"=>"00000000000286920"},
  #    1=>{"ABC"=>"301604", "CDE"=>"1074", "TPP"=>"4971821467", "APD"=>"182",
  #        "PRODUCTID"=>"ACH", "OPP"=>"1199.64", "CTC"=>"00000000000211920"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr1 = %w|CHAR NUMBER NUMBER NUMBER CHAR NUMBER CHAR|
arr2 = [6, [7,0], [15,0], [5,0], 3, [15,2], 17]

types = arr1.zip(arr2)
random_data.map do |_, hash|
  hash.map.with_index do |(k, v), idx|
    type, digits = types[idx]
    [
      k, 
      type == 'NUMBER' ? v.to_i.to_s.tap do |s|
        s[/(?=.{#{[*digits][1]}}\z)/] = '.' unless [*digits][1].zero?
      end : v
    ]
  end
end
```

Comment: When i am trying to execute this code, i am getting below error:

`block (3 levels) in <main>': undefined method `zero?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: It can not be the case with test data you have provided. Anyway, put `unless [*digits][1].nil? || [*digits][1].zero?` instead of `unless [*digits][1].zero?`.